# How to accept objects from one Class into a Subclass of that class

Tags: php

I have two basic classes:

This is my english interpretation of the code:
The Entree class is supposed to take in a name, and then some ingredients (it makes an array out of those), and then there is this hasIngredient function that lets me check if the array has certain elements...

Then there is the PricedEntree class which extends Entree. It inherits a construct, but then also takes the array and uses the "as" and puts it into "ingredient", and cycles through it (via foreach).

I want to use the PricedEntree class, because I want access to the getCost method; but I cannot seem to be able to make a valid instantiation of PricedEntree. I am getting an error saying:

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Elements of $ingredients must be Ingredient objects in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ex_f_6.1.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ex_f_6.1.php(43): PricedEntree->__construct('soup', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ex_f_6.1.php on line 22".
```

What valid arguments do I need to put into PricedEntree? 
Also, what of line #21? I don't know if Entree should be referenced.

Ultimately, I want to access objects that already exist in my parent class from my subclass. 
Note: I am working with David Sklar's Php book.

My code:

```
<?php

class Entree {

public $name;
public $ingredients = array();
public function __construct($name, $ingredients) { if (! is_array($ingredients)) {
throw new Exception('$ingredients must be an array'); }
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->ingredients = $ingredients;
    }
public function hasIngredient($ingredient) {
return in_array($ingredient, $this->ingredients);
} }


class PricedEntree extends Entree {
    public function __construct($name, $ingredients) {
        parent::__construct($name, $ingredients);
        foreach ($this->ingredients as $ingredient) {
            if (! $ingredient instanceof Entree) {  //<---***** I don't know if 'Entree' is used correctly here
                throw new Exception('Elements of $ingredients must be Ingredient objects');
            }
        }
    }

    public function getCost() {
        $cost = 0;
        foreach ($this->ingredients as $ingredient) {
            $cost += $ingredient->getCost();
        }
        return $cost;
    }
}


$soup = new Entree("mushroom_soup", array("yellow_feet","monkey","black_trumpet","toadstool"));
print $soup->name;
print "\r\n";
print_r($soup->ingredients);
print "\r\n";

$monkey_magic = new PricedEntree("soup", array("yellow_feet","monkey","black_trumpet","toadstool"));
print "\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: you are passing an array then checking if its an instance of the Entree class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PricedEntree` class checks to see if the array of ingredients is an array of `Entree` objects, you're sending it an array of strings. This line of code doesn't seem to make any sense:

```
if (! $ingredient instanceof Entree) {  //<---***** I don't know if 'Entree' is used correctly here
    throw new Exception('Elements of $ingredients must be Ingredient objects');
}
```

It looks like you're missing an `Ingredient` class that should be there instead.

Why would the ingredients to your PricedEntree each be an Entree?